# DataBase first в asp.net mvc core как обновить бд?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Я в свой проект добавил, ef database first и после изменил в бд имя таблицы и теперь ошибка `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'EmployeeId'.'`

Дело в том что у меня нет столбца с таким именем даже. Но есть таблица с именем employee и я так понял что `employeeId` это таблица `employee` с полем `Id`
которая на момент создание контекста и подключения бд через `Scaffold-DbContext`
называлась staff и теперь вопрос как обновить бд в проекте?
модель:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TaskTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEnd { get; set; }
    public  Status TypeStatus { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] StaffId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeTasks> StaffTasks { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\;Database=[Your db];Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -force
```

Подробнее тут
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database